# PHP: How to design framework agnostic library that is using entities?

Tags: php, database, oop, frameworks

If library assumes existence of entities but we want to make it as agnostic as possible - is it ok to assume that developer should implement multiple classes before library will be usable, like the repository classes, manager classes and entity classes (assuming we would provide him interfaces/abstract classes)? Is it a proper way of making library a framework/ORM agnostic?

Are there any good examples of framework agnostic libraries that are using entites/database?

Comment: If you want to make your classes framework agnostic you should only rely on your own classes and, in order to extend your functionalities, provide several interfaces which the framework classes can, somehow, implement. I recommend reading a little bit about SOLID principles.